# pretraining cifar 10 network with cifar 100 data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

For finetuning, you will use data from “bus” and “tiger” classes of CIFAR-100 data set. Your task is to find out how to finetune a
pretrained CNN model, use the training data (I think 500 images for each class) “bus” and “tiger” classes for finetuning the network,
and verify the accuracy with the test data (100 images per class) of the same 2 classes. Fine tune can be performed on the selected
layers of the pretrained model. You need to record the test accuracy when you finetune the last layer, last two layers, last three
layers, last four layers, and all five layers

my first question how do i use only bus and tiger from cifar100 and train the model?
Second question is how do i finetune last layer, last two layers etc.

i'm pretraining on cifar 10 and then want to use on bus and tiger from cifar100 to finetune.

Answer (score 2):

> my first question how do I use only bus and tiger from cifar100 and train the model?

Actually it depends on what you want to achieve. Notice that in CIFAR10 there is no class Tiger or Bus. You can use pre-trained network on CIFAR10 to create a new classifier only for two classes (tiger and bus) or add them to already existing 10 classes wherein result you will get a classifier for 12 classes. In both cases, you have to modify the size of the last layer from 10 to 2 or 12.

You need to extract only those pictures that represent a tiger or bus probably using their labels from the CIFAR100 collection and add them to your training set.

> Second question is how do I finetune last layer, last two layers, etc.

You can freeze layers that you don't want to be modified during the training. A freeze means that weights in this considered layer will not be updated by the gradient of loss function during the training process.

How to do this depends on the framework you are using. For example, in Keras, you can set **trainable** parameter of layers you don't want to train to false. See the example below how to freeze all layers in simple CNN except the last two.

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

for layer in model.layers[:-2]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of my first question how to do it please?

Comment: how to do " You can use pre-trained network on CIFAR10 to create a new classifier only for two classes (tiger and bus)"

Comment: @SimonKhan First of all you need to create (example architecture in my answer) and train neural network  with original CIFAR10 dataset. After that you can save your model to file. 
Then as I mentioned earlier, you have to extract Bus and Tiger images from CIFAR100 dataset, load your earlier trained model, change last layer from 10 to 12 output neurons, freeze for example convolutional layers and train your new network with extended dataset again.

Comment: i already trained the model but i don't know how to extract bus and tiger images from CIFAR 100. Can you do a simple demonstration that will help please? i am stuck how to take bus and tiger labels with associated training data.